# How to get a function pointer to a built-in arithmetic operator?

Tags: c++, operators, c++14, function-pointers, built-in

Is there any way in C++ to get a pointer to a built-in arithmetic operator? Something like this [doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a59d50b19fa4c26f):

```
const auto addition = static_cast<int(*)(int, int)>(operator+);
```

A simple workaround of this problem is to [make an auxiliary lambda](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50e6098f2a75e11e):

```
const auto addition = +[](const int a, const int b){ return a + b; };
```

But is there any other solution?

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Comment: Interesting question in its own right but just in case it would help if you described why you need this.

Comment: @SergeyA I don't know. :-(

Comment: @KonradRudolph I simply don't want to make lambdas for all built-in operators I want to have function pointers to. I'm too lazy...

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? This question is a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you ask for help with a solution to a for us unknown problem. What if there are *other* solutions?

Comment: @SergeyA Low research efforts obviously.

Comment: @user0042 [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644816/is-it-possible-to-get-the-function-pointer-of-a-built-in-standard-operator) is the first link in the Google search output for the query "c++ pointer to built-in operator". I should check it before asking my question, of course.

Comment: @Constructor TBF: You couldn't know this particular question exists (it's not very popular), though I do.