# Is it possible to pass a pointer to an operator as an argument like a pointer to a function?

Tags: c++

**I am considering the general case, the following is just a simple example encountered which is easy to handle but has evoked my thoughts.**

For example, I am using the `sort()` function of `<algorithm>`.
Instead of defining a function as

```cpp
bool cmp (int n1, int n2)
{
    return n1 > n2;
}
```

and

```cpp
sort (arr, arr + N, cmp);
```

in the main function, I am wondering whether I can pass a pointer to the operator `>`, just as what I do to a pointer to a function, to the sort function. If so, how do I implement it?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you but I am not just focusing on this specific case. I am considering the general situation.

Comment: Related : [Is it possible to get the function pointer of a built-in standard operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644816/is-it-possible-to-get-the-function-pointer-of-a-built-in-standard-operator).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You cannot obtain a pointer to a built-in operator. But fortunately, the standard library provides function objects for all standard operators. In your case, that object's name is `std::greater`:

```
sort (arr, arr + N, std::greater<int>{});
```

Since C++14, you can even omit the argument type and it will be deduced from how the object is used:

```
sort (arr, arr + N, std::greater<>{});
```

And since C++17, the empty `<>` can be omitted too:

```
sort (arr, arr + N, std::greater{});
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that, but you can use a lambda directly inside the sort, or store the lambda itself in a variable if you need to pass the comparator around

```
sort (arr, arr + N, [](int a, int b){ return a > b; });
```

or

```
auto comp = [](int a, int b){ return a > b; };
sort (arr, arr + N, comp);
```

or as suggested you can use the `std::greater`

```
sort (arr, arr + N, std::greater<>{});
```