# How do I send an operator into std::async?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have currently a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
int main() {
    auto result = std::async([](int left, int right){return left + right;}, 1, 1);
    std::cout<<"from async I get "<<result.get()<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This lambda does nothing but a simple addition, but I just fails to replace it with an operator:

```
auto result = std::async(operator+, 1, 1);
```

The error says `use of undeclared 'operator+'`

How do I fix it, to use an operator to replace the lambda?

Comment: C++ have many [standard operator functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional#Operator_function_objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a reference or function pointer to a builtin operator [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644816/is-it-possible-to-get-the-function-pointer-of-a-built-in-standard-operator), but you can use one of the utilities in the `<functional>` header:

```
auto result = std::async(std::plus<>{}, 1, 1);
```

If you're obsessed with passing a reference to an operator, you can have that with a wrapper type:

```
struct Int { int value; };

Int operator+(const Int& lhs, const Int& rhs)
{
    return Int{lhs.value + rhs.value};
}

auto result = std::async(operator+, Int{1}, Int{1});
std::cout<<"from async I get "<<result.get().value<<"\n";
```

But this is for understanding what works and what doesn't, I am not proposing that you should do that :)

Comment: Does `std::plus` automatically detect my overloaded functions?

Comment: Which overloaded functions?

Comment: Let's say I have my own operator+ overloaded, does `std::plus` takes my function, or does it take the standard one?

Comment: @Koothrappali If you look closely at the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus), you'll see that `std::plus` just basically calls the `+` operator for the given arguments. So yes, if you overloaded that operator, it should be deduced (thanks ADL)

Comment: Ah, `std::plus<>` does nothing else than invoking `+` on both arguments. Like the lambda in your original example.

Comment: @Koothrappali, std::plus is a template with different implementations.  If you give it a type, then it will only add arguments of that type.  For example, std::plus<int> will only take (and return) ints.  However, std::plus<> with no template arguments, is a special templated version that will take any 2 objects of the same type and return "whatever operator+ returns for those things.  So yes, your overloads of any custom types will be used, provided you use `std::plus<>`.